# Tool to do unattended VAPT / security scan of the system(s)

Tags: automation

I am trying to set up an automated VAPT and Security audit tool to test our production systems in detail. The tool needs to run

1. automatically and unattended
2. at regular intervals and
3. tests/audits the system comprehensively

so that we know that our changes to the prod system have reduced the security of the system.

What automation tools are available which can be used to solve the above problem? It can be a paid tool or a free one - however it should be comprehensive enough rely on.

Comment: this seems to be a question to ask for product recommendations, which are out of scope for this forum.

Answer (score 0):

While recommending a specific tool would require a detailed knowledge of your servers, settings, OS and application(s) which this is not the place for I would suggest taking a look at [GRR Rapid Response](https://grr-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which describes itself as:

> GRR Rapid Response is an incident response framework focused on remote
> live forensics.

It will allow you, amongst other things, to schedule and collate the results of system scans, *(which are often platform specific)*, etc.

It is a free (gratis & open source) tool.